# How to shift cell values by month and day indices in a loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I've written a code that compares 2 dataframes cell-wise and depending on the result assigns specific values to each of the cells in the third dataframe. The index of the first two goes month-to-month, and of the latter is day-to-day. The problem is, my code shifts the date and starts to write, e.g., from the second or the third day of the month.

Here are the files:

[1] Q_1: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Oo_E0DhVeSfwcNlwUIyDSWlkwge1BhxP/view?usp=sharing

[2] Q_2:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hwgjokdntyvJKmbY9sGch4XWHJ4oJDq4/view?usp=sharing

[3] Q_3: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1InyyM750EEEYuUZLtC9cY4WjUFz-W1dc/view?usp=sharing

I tried to loop through different ranges, also tried to shift by the amount of days of the previous month. I commented the specific code and now assign only pairs like (day, month) to debug.

```
day_group = Q_3.groupby(by=[Q_3.index.month,Q_3.index.year]).count()
Q_new = pd.DataFrame(columns=Q_3.columns, index=Q_3.index)

Q_diff = Q_1.subtract(Q_2, axis='columns', level=None, fill_value=None)

for i, item in enumerate(Q_2.columns):
    if item not in Q_1.columns:
        continue
    for j in range(0, len(Q_2.index)):
        delta = Q_diff.iloc[j, i]
        num_days_len = day_group.loc[Q_2.index[j].month, Q_month.index[j].year][item] #the amount of days in the corresponding month
        # num_days_prev = day_group.loc[Q_2.index[j - 1].month, Q_month.index[j].year][item]

        for k in range(0, num_days_len):
            if delta == 0:
                Q_new.iloc[k+j*num_days_len, i] = k, j # 0
            if delta > 0:
                Q_new.iloc[k+j*num_days_len, i] = k, j # Q_3.iloc[k+j*(num_days_len), i] + abs(delta)/num_days_len
            elif delta < 0:
                Q_new.iloc[k+j*num_days_len, i] = k, j # Q_3.iloc[k+j*(num_days_len), i] - abs(delta)/num_days_len
```

I expect the code to write correctly the first and last values (well, and everything in between) in the corrsponding cell.

I have now:

```
2013-05-30 00:00:00 (27, 2) (27, 2) (27, 2) (27, 2)
2013-07-04 00:00:00 (0, 4)  (0, 4)  (0, 4)  (0, 4)
```

I need:

```
2013-05-30 00:00:00 (29, 2) (29, 2) (29, 2) (29, 2)
2013-07-04 00:00:00 (4, 4)  (4, 4)  (4, 4)  (4, 4)
```

Please, help me to find the mistake.

Comment: Can you include what the Q's look like? Otherwise we won't know what to make of your expected output.

Comment: @Spinor8, done.